# From java.util.ArrayList to a dictionary in java

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, arraylist, mariadb

Im using a JBPM to make a SQL query in the DB. The sql output is return to a variable that is java.util.ArrayList. The table that im queryin is like this in MariaDB:

```
variable   value
math       1
physics    4
biology    10
...
sport      5
chemistry  9
```

The query that I'm making is `SELECT * from school_data`. It is returning me in a form of list like [math,1,phycics,4,biology,10.....] and only 20 elements.

Is there a way to transform the output in dictionary and then extract the values easly? I python it would be like this:

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from school_data")
result = cur.fetchall()
query_result = dict((x, y) for x, y in result)
math=query_result['math']
physics=query_result['physics']
biology=query_result['biology']
```

Comment: Whatever tool you are using that ends up giving you an array with 20 elements like that? That's your error. Don't do that, that's a bizarre way to approach this problem. It's somewhat unlikely you'd want `SELECT *` here in the first place. You probably want to make a java class with fields that have types that match your expected output, and then ask the DB abstraction to turn those rows into instances of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have lists or dictionaries / maps as built-in data types, so it does not offer syntax or built-in operators for working with them.  One can certainly perform transformations such as you describe, but it's a matter of opinion whether it can be done "easily".  One way would be something like this:

```
Map<String, String> query_result = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < result_array.length; i += 2) {
    query_result.put(result_array[i], result_array[i + 1]);
}

String biology = query_result.get("biology");
// ...
```

That makes some assumptions about the data types involved, which you might need to adjust for your actual data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea @John, I modified it a little bit and it worked.